# Is there an equivalent to an \Sinput{} command in Knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

How do I insert single R commands (e.g., summary()) formatted as they would be by \begin{Sinput} ... \end{Sinput} in my Rnw file?

Comment: I do not know what you are asking. Please provide a minimal example and show what you want.

Comment: I want to insert e.g., \Sexpr{summary()} to be echoed but not executed.

Comment: Okay, why not `\texttt{summary()}`?